# Determine the $MLE$ of $\theta$

Tags: statistics

Let $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ be an observed sample from a distribution with probability density function given by

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2 \theta^3} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}, x > 0$$

$0$ otherwise

(a) Determine the $MLE$ of $\theta$

(b) Determine the $MLE$ of $\psi(\theta) = Var(X_1)$

Solution:

(a)

$L(\theta | \bar{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i^2}{2 \theta^3} e^{-\frac{x_i}{\theta}} = \left(\frac{1}{2\theta^3} \right)^n \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 \right) e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i} = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 \right) e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}\bar{x}}$

Log-likelihood is:

$$\ln L = n \ln \frac{1}{2 \theta^3} + 2 \ln \bar{x} - \frac{1}{\theta}\bar{x}$$

the derivative of this with respect to $\theta$ would be

$0 = \frac{-3n}{\theta} + 0 + \frac{\bar{x}}{\theta^2}$

solve for theta we get

$$\theta = \frac{\bar{x}}{3n}$$

therefore thats the $MLE$

(b)

Notice how $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ ~ $Gamma(3, \frac{1}{\theta})$

variance for gamma is given is $Var(X) = \frac{a}{b^2} = \frac{3}{\frac{1}{\theta^2}} = 3 \theta^2$

$\theta = \frac{\bar{x}}{3n}$ from (a)

so

$$= 3 \frac{\bar{x}^2}{9n^2} = \frac{\bar{x}^2}{3n^2}$$

would this be right?

Comment: Looks good to me (with the assumption that $\theta>0$).

Comment: Why not simply edit the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138512/determine-the-mle-of-theta)? You are being careless writing the likelihood and log-likelihood.